# jQuery mobile single page template loading content via ajax

Tags: google-maps, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm creating mobile app with `phonegap`, `google maps` and `jquery mobile`. I would like to have more then one single html templates files (navigation for pages) and load just the content of the page via `ajax` to `javascript` overlay.

Also i want to keep the history and hashes to be able to go back to previous page etc. I tried using `$.mobile.loadPage` and `changePage` but this is changing the whole pages and i would like to change just the content.

Is there any solution?

Comment: I hope you add some code you tried. so we can help more :)

Comment: You cannot load just the content because JQM loads the whole page(header,content and footer). to load an external page use $.mobile.changePage("file.html") with transition in the options if needed

Answer (score 0):

You will find [this framework](http://cordova.codeplex.com/) the exact one you are looking for.